# How much magnesium is in Hinode Calrose rice?

Tags: rice, nutrient-composition

I was looking for foods high in magnesium and I stumbled into Calrose rice. One source said 3000% for a quarter cup which is rediculous must be mistake but there is no other source that talks about magnesium content.

So I assume it has probably never been measured. Does anybody know?

Comment: Can you link the source of where you got the 3000% value ?

Comment: 3000% of **what**?

Comment: @wumpus  I asked the administrator of the website and he emailed me back and said it was a mistake , thanked me for bringing it to his attention and he will delete it. Sorry for all the confusion. Next time I will be more careful what I choose to believe. Lesson learned.

Comment: @sedumjoy You did the right thing: ask when a confusing statement presents itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.health.harvard.edu/healthy-eating/magnesium-content-in-milligrams-mg-of-certain-foods) shows that 1 cup of cooked brown rice contains 80mg of magnesium. and white rice contains 50mg.

The wikipedia for [brown rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_rice) show that for 100g of raw rice it contains 143mg of magnesium, and for white rice it's about 127mg.

The wikipedia page for [calrose rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calrose_rice) does not display nutritional information.

I would imagine it is similar to regular white rice or it would be stated, especially if it was 3000% of the base value (or about 3810mg) which would be very high.